# How do I create a timeout function for a nested function inside a threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, python-multithreading, schedule

I am using the [schedule python library](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) inside my main.py file to run the following functions on a schedule:

```py
def start_scheduler():

    # clear board sunday at 9:01pm PST
    schedule.every().monday.at("04:01").do(vp.clear_board)

    # get new games/matches everyday at 9:05pm PST
    schedule.every(1).day.at("04:05").do(vp.generate_board)

    # every 5 mins run update_board
    schedule.every(2).minutes.do(update_matches_with_timeout)
   
    print(schedule.jobs)

    while True:
        try:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Something went wrong in the scheduler: {e}')

scheduler_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_scheduler)
scheduler_thread.start()
```

I'm pretty sure I need start_scheduler in a separate thread so the rest of the `main.py` stuff works. I want to implement timeout functionality to the `update_matches_with_timeout()` function so that if it takes longer than 1 minute to finish executing, I just return nothing and the schedule continues as normal. Assume this is my `update_matches_with_timeout()` function (I am using `time.sleep` to test if it actually returns early if it takes longer than 1 minute to finish executing):

```py
def update_matches_with_timeout():
    print("Function started")
    for i in range(80):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Function stopped")
```

I've tried the following code before, and have been able to print something at the 60-second mark, but I have not been able to stop the function and return early. Somehow 61-80 and "function stopped" are still printed.

```py
def update_matches_with_timeout():
    timeout = 60  # timeout in seconds

    # define the function to run on timeout
    def on_timeout():
        print('update_matches timed out 1')
        raise TimeoutError()

    # create a Timer object to run the on_timeout function after the timeout duration
    timer = threading.Timer(timeout, on_timeout)

    try:
        # start the timer
        timer.start()

        update_matches()
        print("update_matches successfully ran")

    finally:
        # always cancel the timer to prevent it from running after the function has completed
        timer.cancel()
```

Comment: The solutions I've tried from that post do not seem to work with multi-threading, unless I am using them incorrectly.

Comment: can you please explore if this is working for you stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call ?